# Format JSON string before displaying it in MVC? (with datatables)

Tags: json, ajax, model-view-controller, format, datatables

Got a nice JSON problem over here;

I don't know how to go about formatting date, timespan, decimals etc before sending it to the view in MVC. I'm using the datatables jQuery plugin, and my 'DataHandler' method returns a JSON object as source for the datatable.

When I was processing the data and filtering client-side it was pretty straightforward, but now I'm processing the data on the server-side.

**Controller:**

```
 public JsonResult DataHandler(DTParameters param)
        {
            try
            {
                var dtsource = new List<spRegistrations_Result>();
                using (entities dc = new entities())
                {
                    dtsource = dc.spRegistrations().ToList();
                }

                List<String> columnSearch = new List<string>();

                foreach (var col in param.Columns)
                {
                    columnSearch.Add(col.Search.Value);
                }

                List<spRegistrations_Result> data = new ResultSet().GetResult(param.Search.Value, param.SortOrder, param.Start, param.Length, dtsource, columnSearch);
                int count = new ResultSet().Count(param.Search.Value, dtsource, columnSearch);
                DTResult<spRegistrations_Result> result = new DTResult<spRegistrations_Result>
                {
                    draw = param.Draw,
                    data = data,
                    recordsFiltered = count,
                    recordsTotal = count
                };
                return Json(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { error = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

**Table initialization:**

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "type": "POST",
                "url": '/Table/DataHandler',
                "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'data': function (data) { return data = JSON.stringify(data); }
            },
            "drawCallback": function(settings){
                $('.card').hide();
            },
            "paging": true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "columns": [
           { "data": "RegId" },
           { "data": "PresenceDate" }, etc...
```

**Model:**

```
 public int RegId { get; set; }
 public System.TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
 public System.TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
 public System.DateTime PresenceDate { get; set; }
```

[This is how it looks when the table is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE1Bx.png)

As you can see, the date is not very nicely formatted, and is the reason that I want to format  the data before displaying it. Same goes for a couple of TimeSpan objects etc that I eventually want to show in the table.

I'm still pretty new to ajax, and don't know how to go about this the easiest way. Thanks for any input !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) property to define the content of the table cell, using a custom js function to format the date. Something like:

```
...
"render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
      var date = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6), 0));
      return ISODateString(date);
}
```

The function to format the date dd/mmm/yyyy:

```
function ISODateString(d) {
    function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n }
    return pad(d.getDate()) + '/' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I solved it using this technique. Looks beautiful now :)